# htaccess gzip and browser caching

Tags: performance, .htaccess, pagespeed

On https://bm-translations.de I am trying to activate gzip compress and browser caching via .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bm-translations.de/$1 [L,R=301]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s7 !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 21600000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Out of some reasons Page-Speed Insights is still showing both is not activated as you can see here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=de&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbm-translations.de
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it possible to upload the ressources as gzip already instead or will this cause errors somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen instances of cache delay from server.  In other words, it might just take time to recognize gzip compression.  Below is a working example of mine.

```
    ## Enable gzip compression ##
    # compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

    # Remove browser bugs
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    ## END Enable gzip compression ##
```

Comment: this works, great thank you! But still problem with cache.

Comment: That's great, I see the site is now gzipped. For cache, see the following https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzzBvW